# mouse hover, css div effect, alpha and new button

Tags: css, hover, effect

I have a little question.

I have div 200*200 px. I need effect:
- when user mouse hover on div: alpha 70% black picture
- show new button at middle of picture (or textual link) for example "Add to cart"

You can see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/t8jPN

```
    <div class="wrapper">
<div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">NEW</div></div>
<img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2011/05/summer-dresses4.jpg"></img>
</div>

.wrapper {
margin: 50px auto;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: white;
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
position: relative;
z-index: 90;
}

.ribbon-wrapper-green {
width: 85px;
height: 88px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: -3px;
right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;

-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
position: relative;
padding: 7px 0;
left: -5px;
top: 15px;
width: 120px;
background-color: #BFDC7A;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
color: #6a6340;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
content: "";
border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
border-left:  3px solid transparent;
border-right: 3px solid transparent;
position:absolute;
bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
right: 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: post the code you have please

Comment: I edit post and paste code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is have wrapper for three divs. One div with the image, one div with the shadow and other for the button.

The reason there are separate divs for the shadow and the button (or link) is to avoid the transparency effect on the button.

I guess there are better ways to solve the problem but i would use this one because i find it easier.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/a97FS/10/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .contenedor{
                position:relative;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid black;

            }
            .atCorner{
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;

            }
            .escondido{
                display: none;    
            }
            .shadow{
                background-color: black;
                zoom: 1;
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                opacity: 0.7;

            }
            .button{
                text-align: center;    
            }
            .button button{
                margin-top: 40%;

            }   
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.contenedor').mouseenter(function(){
                jQuery(this).find('.shadow, .button').fadeIn();
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                jQuery(this).find('.shadow, .button').fadeOut();
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="atCorner" id="picture">
                <img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2011/05/summer-dresses4.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="atCorner escondido shadow" id="">
            </div>    
            <div class="atCorner escondido button" id="">    
                <button>Buy it</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```